# Is it possible to return my Firestore stream as a List of models?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I made a group service that provides a group stream. This stream is of type `Stream<List<GroupModel>>` but I don't really know how I can map the Firestore stream in such a way that I get a `Stream<List<GroupModel>>`. This is what I have thus far.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:wally_talk/data/models/group_model.dart';

class GroupService {

  static const groupCollectionKey = 'groups';
  final CollectionReference groupCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection(groupCollectionKey);

  Stream<List<GroupModel>> groupStream(String userID) {
    return groupCollection
        .where('members', arrayContains: userID)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) =>
            snapshot.documents.map((document) => GroupModel.fromMap(id: document.documentID, data: document.data)));
  }

  Future postGroup(String groupName) async {
    // return await groupCollection.add(Group();
  }
}
```

And this is my group model

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

class GroupModel
{
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final List<String> memberIDs;
  final String adminID;

  GroupModel({@required this.id, @required this.name, @required this.memberIDs, @required this.adminID}) 
  : assert(id != null),
  assert(name != null),
  assert(memberIDs != null),
  assert(adminID != null);

  factory GroupModel.fromMap({@required String id, @required Map data})
  {
    return GroupModel(
      id: id,
      name: data['name'] ?? '',
      memberIDs: data['members'] ?? List<String>(),
      adminID: data['adminID'] ?? '',
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap()
  {
    return Map.fromEntries([
      MapEntry<String, String>('id', id),
      MapEntry<String, String>('name', name),
      MapEntry<String, String>('adminID', adminID)
    ]);
  }
}
```

And currently I get the following message from the terminal

```
AsyncSnapshot<List<GroupModel>>(ConnectionState.active, null, type 'MappedListIterable<DocumentSnapshot, GroupModel>' is not a subtype of type 'List<GroupModel>')
```

When I call it from my StreamBuilder with

```
stream: groupService.groupStream(userProvider.user.uid),
```

Comment: try to add an toList(); at the end of your return statement of the stream

Comment: I did try that and it becomes a `Future<List<Iterable<GroupModel>>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Stream<List<GroupModel>> groupStream(String userID) {
return groupCollection
    .where('members', arrayContains: userID)
    .snapshots()
    .map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((document) =>
        GroupModel.fromMap(id: document.documentID, data: document.data)).toList());
```

Sorry I meant to put it there, my fault. this should work, Ihave a similar stream working like this!